# How to find the maximum of infected population (epidemy model)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system:
$$\begin{cases}
\dot S=-kSI   \\
\dot I=kSI-rI
\end{cases}$$
where S(t) are the people susceptible to getting sick by 1000, and I(t) are the ones infected with the disease by 1000, k measures the speed with which the disease is transmitted, r is the rate of recovering (the one that got sick can no longer get sick again, it is immune).

I belive the reason is called *simplified* is because they are not considering the people who get sick again or the people who dies.

The exercise asks the find the values of S when I peaks (ie, when it gets to its maximum), and to find the phase plane.

For the first thing I'm not sure what to do. When it comes to maximums, I immediately think of calculus, and local maximums, but what I get looks a little bit ridiculous:  first I took the homogenous ecuation $\dot I=kSI-rI=0$ which is $(kS(t)-r)I(t)=0$ and if we take the derivative: $(k\dot S(t))I(t)+(kS(t)-r)\dot I(t)=0$. From here, after doing some calculations I got to a dead end, am I using the correct way? How would I know if I'm right?

For the phase plane,  I'm not sure what to  do either. I belive you first you have to find the eigen vectors, but for that you need the matrix associated to the system, and I don't know if that's possible, since this one is not even coupled. What do you do in this cases?

Comment: Well, it's not a dead end. You were asked to find values of $S$ for which $I$ peaks. Of course first you have to find the points for which $\dot{I} = 0$. Then you should check the sign of $\ddot{I}$ at these points. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @Evgeny When does this happen $\dot I=I(kS-r)=0$? If I=0, or if $kS-r=0$, ie, $S=\frac rk$. If there are no sick people, then $\dot I=0$, so this case is not relevant (I think). So, when does $S(t)=\frac rk$??, for which $t$ this is valid? We don't have much information about S, the only thing we have is its differential ecuation, and r and k are constants. If we substitute $S(t)=\frac rk$ in $\dot S=-kSE$ we get $\dot S=-k(\frac rk)E=-rE$, that is $\dot S=-rE(t)$ for some t. But I still can't find the t. I can't even say we can take t=0, because we don't know if that's when no one was sick or

Comment: It's very unlikely that you'll find this particular moment of time when $S = \frac{r}{k}$. So, it's reasonable to stick to phase variables and solve this task using them.

Comment: @Evgeny Thanks for the recommendation, but I don't know what are _phase variables_, where can I find that?

Comment: When you're studying system $x' = F(x), \; x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \; F(x) \colon \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$, $x$ belongs to *phase space*. In your case you have *phase plane* $(S, I)$ and both $S$ and $I$ are *phase variables*.

Comment: @Evgeny Oh! I see, sorry for the dumb question, I'm not used to see them named like that. Ok, but I'm not sure what you mean by stick to them. Should I make $I$ tend to infinity and see what happens to S? I'm sorry, is just I can't seem to find a way to even expres the maximum of I without getting something like before